# MissingPluginException(No implementation found in flutter using geolocator

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin

i am using geolocator in flutter project to get current location but this error come on it.
i added all dependencies in both ios and android files still get this error i dont know why
flutter channel stable, 2.12,

here is my code:

```
Position position = await Geolocato.getCurrentPosition( desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
```

here is my error coming which i tested android 10, 8 also, but answer same

```
Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getCurrentPosition on channel flutter.baseflow.com/geolocator)
```

i am using geolocator plugin here is plugin link :https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator

Comment: Sometimes its just because of old plugin cache. Try `flutter clean` and rebuild you app. Hopefully it will work fine

Comment: tried  a lot but nothin works, app close then again run as same android studio did, but nothing changed

Comment: I used same plugin in one of my apps and it was working fine. Try the code here might help you https://github.com/m-hamzashakeel/Here-I-Am-Alert-App

Comment: @Hamza you add this plugin but not use anywhere i  see no location permission anything else.

Comment: the locations will be on button press and same goes for permission. The file will be homeScreen or something like that

Comment: This solution worked for me: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74781329/9805273)

Answer (score 4):

Running `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` fixed the issue for me. I uninstalled the application, cleared the cache of my device and rebuilt the app. This time there was a popup asking to give location permission to the app.

I gave the access and got the current position of the device (latitude and longitude).

Also make sure you upgrade flutter to 3.0.0 by running `flutter upgrade`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe someone will need my solution. This happens because GeolocatorPlatform.instance is not initialized. Call _registerPlatformInstance() where you need.

```
import 'package:geolocator_android/geolocator_android.dart';
import 'package:geolocator_apple/geolocator_apple.dart';

void _registerPlatformInstance() {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      GeolocatorAndroid.registerWith();
    } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      GeolocatorApple.registerWith();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Stop running the app completely and restart the app.
make sure that the app is killed before restart
click stop button, refer below,

[image]

Comment: Thats correct and probably the simplest way to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

If you just installed the package (`geolocator`), just restart the app or even better the phone.

Comment: restarting helped. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your flutter
Run on terminal `flutter upgrade`
or `flutter upgrade —-force`
Then =>`flutter pub outdated`
Then =>`flutter pub upgrade`
After that =>`flutter pub upgrade —-major-versions`

Finally go to

> yourProjectName/android/app/build.gradle

Change:

```
android {
   compileSdkVersion ##
…
…
}
```

To:

```
android {
   compileSdkVersion 33
…
…
}
```